# How to pass multiple variable in a For -Each Controller of Jmeter

Tags: foreach, jmeter

{"seatNumb":null,"seqNum":1,"myJourneyID":${MYID},"primaryDoc":null,"secdoc":null}

I have the above request in a for-each controller where i can control myJourneyID but in all the request the seqNum also changes. How to control both the variable in a single for-each ?

Answer (score 1):

As per JMeter version 3.3 you can use only a single variable in the ForEach Controller. If you need to amend this `seqNum` value as well go for [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function or [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element and implement iteration on second variable manually.

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)